# Ubuntu Software Center rendering glitch with NVIDIA drivers

Tags: software-center, fonts

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 in my HDD, after that I had some problems because I couldn't boot Ubuntu and the pc booted with Windows instead. (Dual boot screen didn’t appear). I solved this through boot repair. But now my fonts on Ubuntu Software Center are like this:

[image: Glitched Ubuntu Software Centre Window]

From what I've noticed, this is the only program affected. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This issue can be caused by a corrupted install of the NVIDIA drivers.

1. Go to `System Settings`n then  `Software Sources` and then the `Additional Drivers` tab.
2. Select `Using X.Org server...` and click `Apply Changes`
3. Restart your computer
4. Go back to `Additional Drivers`
5. Re-enable `Using NVIDIA binary Xorg drivers...` and click `Apply Changes`
6. Restart your computer again and the driver issue should be fixed.

For assistance navigating the `Additional Drivers` menu in Ubuntu 12.10, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/201524/72212).

Comment: I have added this workaround to the [bug on LaunchPad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1015216/comments/14).

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think this is related to the fonts themselves. It could be a graphics driver problem. See [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1015216).