# Why am I getting weird glitchy buttons and text?

Tags: unity, graphics

[image: Software Center]

As you can see from the picture, I just installed Ubuntu on my system and I am getting some strange Glitchy graphics. This also happens in the Password field on Login.

Any  ideas what this could be and how I can fix it? It doesn't happen when running other Desktop Enviroments like GNOME.

Comment: See if your issue is related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/256919/ubuntu-software-center-rendering-glitch-with-nvidia-drivers

Answer (score 0):

Try `unity -- reset`. If not, re-install Unity from the software centre. You will have to do this in another environment like GNOME, or Unity will go bonkers when you uninstall it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tried going into my Synaptic Package Manager and now I get this error message:

E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.  E: _cache->open() failed, please report.

Comment: I would do this command: `dpkg --configure -a` to solve the problem.